# Does not get heading the href content When i click the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, href

If click the link the sript executed But the heading doesnt included the href content

HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?register=reg"><img src="button2.png" id="button2" class="button"></a>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#button2").on('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 
$("#button2").css("display","none"); 
$("#main").css("display","none"); 
$("#register").css("display","block"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#button2").on('click', function(e){ 
   // e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#button2").css("display","none"); 
    $("#main").css("display","none"); 
    $("#register").css("display","block"); 
    });
```

remove the line e.preventDefault() function it will work fine.

Comment: If remove e.preventDefault(); the script doesnt work e.preventDefault(); or return false need to work the script